# Access static object property through variable name

Tags: php, variables, object, object-properties

I know its possible to access an object property/method using a variable as its name

ex.:

```
$propName = 'something';
$something = $object->$propName;
```

Is it possible to do the same w/ constants or static properties?

I've tried:

$constName = 'MY_CONST';

```
MyCLass::{$constName};
```

and

```
$obj::{$constName};
```

But nothing seems to work and I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use: `Class::$$constName`, this is similar to normal [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Demo:

```
<?php    
class MyClass {
    public static $var = 'A';
}
$name = 'var';
echo MyClass::$$name; // echoes 'A'
```

Constants can be access with the [`constant`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
constant('MyClass::'.$constantName)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<?php
class Test {
  public static $nombre = "pepe";

  public function __construct() {
    return self;
  }
}

$varName = "nombre";
echo Test::${$varName};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constant function:

```
constant('bar::'. $const);
constant("$obj::". $const); //note the double quote
```

Comment: your 1st example worked, but i've tried the second way and it sent the error: "Object of class tst could not be converted to string", even with the double quoted string. thanks for your answer anyway